# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'people' of undefined "

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am trying to use the Plus API to sign a user in. I get the following error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'people' of undefined`

This is my logic for loading and getting profile info:

```
var firstName;
$(document).ready(function () {
  function loadGApi() {
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1');
  }
  $('#loaderror').hide();
});

function signInCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
    // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
    // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
    $('#gConnect').hide();
    $('#authOps').show('slow');
    $('#profile').append(
      $('<p>Hello ' + getProfile(firstName) + '</p>'));
    console.log(authResult);

  } else {
    // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
    // Possible error values:
    //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
    //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
    //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
    console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}

function getProfile(profile) {
  var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
    'userId': 'me'
  });
  if (profile == firstName) {
    request.execute(function (gprofile) {
      return gprofile.displayName;
    });
  }
}
```

and this is how I am loading the script:

```
(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script');
  po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=loadGApi';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

I apologize if this is an noob question but I hope learn more about Javascript and using the G+ API!

Comment: That error is saying that `gapi.client.plus` doesn't exist.

Comment: @elclanrs Yes, I realized that but I don't understand why it isnt loaded? Thanks for your help!

Comment: you never call `loadGApi()` after you declare it. Why is it being declared inside jQuery 'ready`?

Comment: Not sure, haven't used G+ API but something tells me that this is an async issue, and that you should be using a callback somewhere... But I could be wrong, maybe somebody else can help.

Comment: @charlietfl Hmmm. I guess it dosnt need to be in the 'ready' but it is called in when the Google API is loaded in right here 'po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=loadGApi';' It is passed as a URL argument as the documentation. ALso I appreciate your help

Comment: @elclanrs That may be the case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works, your inject asynchronously the Google+ javascript client. When this is donem it calls

```
gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1');
```

but [gapi.client.load](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript?#gapiclientloadname_version_callback) takes 3 parameters, the 3rd one being the callback called when the Google+ API is loaded.

Since you didn't specify a callback, nothing is done.

See the [samples](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples), they define the `makeRequest` callback:

```
gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1', makeRequest);
```

and

```
function makeRequest() {
  var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.get({
    'shortUrl': 'http://goo.gl/fbsS'
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    appendResults(response.longUrl);
  });
}
```

So you want to do something like:

```
gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', onGapiLoaded);
```

and

```
function onGapiLoaded() {
  // now you can request Google+ api
}
```

More specifically the [Google+ API samples](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript#LoadingtheclientlibraryandtheAPI) give an example of what you can have in the onGapiLoaded callback:

```
// Returns a request object which can be executed (as below) or batched
var request = gapi.client.METHOD_NAME(PARAMETERS_OBJECT);
request.execute(callback);
```

Example: you can send a search request to the Google+ API using the following method:

```
var request = gapi.client.plus.activities.search({'query': 'Google+', 'orderBy': 'best'});
request.execute(function(resp) { console.log(resp); });
```

Comment: In the documentation it says a callback is optional: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript   If I did use a callback how would I make it so I could use the API in multiple functions that are all called diffrent ways

Comment: The callback is optional indeed: You did not specify it, and no error was thrown.

Comment: Once the Gapi is loaded you can use it as much as you want. The callback may simply decorate your UI with the different callbacks you have.

Answer (score 1):

Just because Google's APIs can be a pain sometimes, here's an example using a promise instead of a callback. (I'm not able to trigger an error with the `load` method, even with an invalid API name, so I omitted that function.)

For context, this was inside a Knockout.js ViewModel in a separate JS file. The `ko.applyBindings` call is made inside the main HTML page, using dependency injection for the `gapi` to keep it in the proper scope. The `authenticate()` method is called from within an init function, and I nested the `client.load()` inside the callback to deal with "not authenticated" errors.

```
function myVM(gapi) {
    var _gapi = gapi;
    var self = this;

    self.authenticate = function() {
        console.log("Loading Google API...");
        _gapi.load('auth', function(param) {
            console.log("Authenticating...");
            _gapi.auth.authorize({
                client_id: '1234',
                immediate: false, /* Needs to be false for initial authorization. Setting to true will prevent the subsequent popups. */
                response_type: 'token',
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content'
            }, function (token) {
                if (token.access_token) {
                    console.log('Authorized!');
                    self.authorized(true);
                    _gapi.client.load('content', 'v2').then(function() {
                        // Do stuff
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('Authorization failed!');
                    self.authorized(false);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```